# Flutter position fixed equivalent

Tags: dart, flutter

Is it possible to fix an object in the screen that stays fixed regardless of scrolling?

Something similar to CSS position fixed.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You can absolutely position a child of a [`Stack`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widget using the [`Positioned`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) widget.

The minimal example below places the red box above the list view, by placing the child in a Positioned widget *after* the ListView in the Stack's children.

```dart
List<String> todos = [...];
return new Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    new ListView(
     children: todos
       .map((todo) => new ListTile(title: new Text(todo)))
       .toList(),
     ),
     new Positioned(
       left: 30.0,
       top: 30.0,
       child: new Container(
         width: 100.0,
         height: 80.0,
         decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
         child: new Text('hello'),
        )
      ),
   ],
);
```

And here it is inside of a `Scaffold` body. If you add more items you'll find that the list scrolls without moving the red box.

[image: an absolutely positioned example]

Comment: I'm using Stack and Positioned but when I add left or right or bottom or top property in the Positioned Its child hide.

Comment: @AliAzad the positioned needs to be the last child of the stack

Answer (score 6):

You could use [Positioned](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) widget in a [Stack](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) Widget with [AspectRatio](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AspectRatio-class.html) widget and use the % distance like the below code.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size; //get the screen size

List<String> todos = [...];

//the below if to get the aspect ratio of the screen i am using the app only in landscape
//if you need to use it in portrait you should add the sizes below
if((size.width / size.height) > 1.76){
  aspect = 16 / 9;
}else if((size.width / size.height) < 1.77 && (size.width / size.height) >= 1.6){
  aspect = 16 / 10;
}else{
  aspect = 4 /3;
}

return new Scaffold(
  body: new Center(
      //layoutBuilder i can use the constraints to get the width and height of the screen
      child: new LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
        return new AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: aspect,
          child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
               new ListView(
                    children: todos
                    .map((todo) => new ListTile(title: new Text(todo)))
                    .toList(),
               ),
               new Positioned(
                    //constraints.biggest.height to get the height 
                    // * .05 to put the position top: 5%
                    top: constraints.biggest.height * .05,
                    left: constraints.biggest.width * .30,
                    child: new Container(
                              width: 100.0,
                              height: 80.0,
                              decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
                              child: new Text('hello'),
                          ),
                    ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      }),
    ),
  );
}
}
```

Hope it will help you....

Comment: I'm using Stack and Positioned but when I add left or right or bottom or top property in the Positioned Its child hide.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer this solution:

```
Stack(
  children: [
    Column(
      children: [
        Container(...),
        Container(...),
      ]
    ),
    Positioned(top:50, child: Card(...))
  ]
)
```

Comment: Don't forget width and height when the child is an image

Answer (score -1):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
  children: [
    Container(
      // covers 20% of total height
      height: 200,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 300,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            left: 0,
            width: 100,
            height: 100,
            child: Container(
              height: 54,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

}

Adding a width and height to your Positioned widget will make it appear if you want to use top/left/bottom/right