# Flutter - Fixed position in a bidirectional scroll

Tags: android, listview, scroll, dart, flutter

is there any way I can implement a bidirectional scroll list where a part of it has a fixed position?
I mean, for example a table that has a legend in the top for each column, I want to keep that legend when I scroll up/down but I also want it to have functionality with the scroll right/left with the rest of the content.
(I know how to implement a bidirectional scroll list, that is not what I am asking for)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49566752/flutter-position-fixed-equivalent try the answers in this question, the question seems a bit similar

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your scrollable into a `Stack` with positioned children to render that fixed position content

```
new Stack(
  children: [
    myScrollable,
    new Positioned(
      top: .0,
      right: .0,
      bottom: .0,
      child: new Container(width: 42.0, color: Colors.red),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: But if I scroll the listview the positioned won't move with it, it will keep its position static, won't it?

Comment: Yes. That's what a fixed position is in css anyway.

Comment: I was looking for something fixed in a axis but scrollable in the other