# Flutter: how to create widget positioned relative to the screen?

Tags: flutter, layout, positioning

Basically I need to create some kind of Snackbar widget that can be created on any page. So I need to make it positioned relative to the screen. The only idea is to create the main Stack widget which will wrap all other pages. Do you have any other ideas? I found [pretty similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49566752/flutter-position-fixed-equivalent) without any interesting answers

Answer (score 1):

By using `Mediaquery`to retrieve the screen size.

For example we can the screen width like this :

```
MediaQueryData screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
```

let's say i want my container's size to take up half the screen's size

One way to go about it is like this :

```
Container(
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
child: Text('This container is half this device screen's size');
);
```

What you are going for here is using the `Positioned` widget

Let's take the last example and leave a quarter of the screen on every side :

```
    Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
    child: child: Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
        left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/4,
        top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4,
        right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/4,
        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/4,
        child: Text('This container is half this device screen's size'),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```