# Flutter: Is there a way to add a floating action button inside a container?

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to add a floating action button inside a container? Or at least achieve a similar effect?

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Padding(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('Hello'),
            SizedBox(height: 30),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: TaskList(),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Ps. I can't use scaffold for a few reasons so don't suggest that.

Comment: of course. Add floating action button as a child of Container.

Comment: @JohnJoe No I can't use FAB as child. The container already has a child and multiple grandchildren.

Comment: As FAB already exists in the world of Flutter material you'll need to provide additional info of the widget tree you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter position fixed equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49566752/flutter-position-fixed-equivalent)

Comment: @xlsra while it does kinda work, it messes up the layout of the screen. Moreover it doesn't occupy the default FAB position either. Ps. I can't use scaffold for a few reasons so don't suggest that.

Comment: @xlsra I played around with it a little bit. Works just as intended. I used stack and then wrapped FAB in align to align it to bottom right. Thanks!

Comment: why FAB when you can use a circular button in a container ?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can utilize `child` property of `Container`

```
Container (
    child: FloatingActionButton()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Container in `floatingActionButton:` after Flutter 2.0
[image]

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
floatingActionButton: GestureDetector(
              onTap: (){},
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal:15),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: AppColors.accentColor2,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
                    ),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: const [
                            Text('Attendence Summary',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,color: Colors.white,fontSize: 12),),
                            Text('Present : 20  | Absentees : 10',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontSize: 14),),
                          ],
                        ),
                        const Text('Review',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),)
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )
```